# Flutter: Get data from native activity to Flutter Widget?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I have a Flutter app that lunch a native activity that contains a form (first and last name fields), when I fill in the fields and click the finish button I want to get these data back to Flutter widget.

Basically, all what I did, was lunch the FormActivity, how can I get the form data from FormActivity and display them on my Flutter widget?

```
override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
                call, result ->
            if (call.method == "lunchActivity") {
               
                val intent = Intent(this, FormActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This might help -  https://medium.com/@andymobitec/flutter-sending-data-between-android-and-flutter-1e0693fbae64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) to launch an activity, return a result from the activity with [setResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)), implement [ActivityResultListener](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/PluginRegistry.ActivityResultListener.html) to handle the result and finally call [success](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/MethodChannel.Result.html#success(java.lang.Object)) on a channel to return the result to Flutter side.

See [details](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-kotlin-tab#step-3-add-an-android-platform-specific-implementation) for Flutter - Android communication.